# Implement case insensitive NSMutableDictionary

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance

I've tried to inherit from `NSMutableDictionary<NSString *,NSString *>` in order to implement dictionary with case insensitive keys. Here's my implementation :

```
@interface NSMutableDictionaryLowerCase : NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, NSString *>
@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionaryLowerCase
    
-(NSString *)objectForKey:(NSString *)aKey {
    return [[super objectForKey:aKey] lowercaseString];
}

@end
```

```
NSMutableDictionaryLowerCase * x = [NSMutableDictionaryLowerCase new];
    
[x setValue:@"XxX" forKey:@"YyY"];

NSLog(@" %@ %@ ", x[@"xxx"], x[@"XXX"])
```

However, when using it with the following code it caught exception on `setValue` with the following message :

`[NSMutableDictionary setObject:forKey:]: method only defined for abstract class.  Define -[NSMutableDictionaryLowerCase setObject:forKey:]!'`

I don't understand, `NSMutableDictionary` shouldn't be abstract class, I thought this method implementation already there... what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

From the doc of [`NSMutableDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsmutabledictionary):

**Subclassing Notes**

There should typically be little need to subclass `NSMutableDictionary`. If you do need to customize behavior, it is often better to consider composition rather than subclassing.

**Methods to Override**

In a subclass, you must override both of its primitive methods:

- setObject(_:forKey:)
- removeObject(forKey:)

You must also override the primitive methods of the `NSDictionary` class.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Larme, here's the fix :

```
@interface NSMutableDictionaryLowerCase : NSMutableDictionary<NSString*, NSString *> {
    NSMutableDictionary* _proxy;
}
@end

@implementation NSMutableDictionaryLowerCase

- (instancetype)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _proxy = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString *)objectForKey:(NSString *)aKey {
    return [_proxy objectForKey:[aKey lowercaseString]];
}

-(void)setObject:(NSString *)anObject forKey:(NSString *)aKey{
    [_proxy setObject:anObject forKey:[aKey lowercaseString]];
}

@end
```